# Jenkins Service Star failed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

i was using `sudo apt-get install jenkins`  to install newest jenkins 2.107.2
but it's start fail with msg:
`Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

and i run `systemctl status jenkins.service` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bRgs.png)

btw, my jdk is:

```
➜  ~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

i have try to re-install and it's not works

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove jenkins
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove jenkins
```

and i am sure is not the issue of port occupy 
can anyone help me to fix this issue ?
thank very munch.

Comment: Did you try `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: yes, it's just say *jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7*

Answer (score 0):

Need to update prep-scripts to ensure that that /etc/sysconfig/jenkins's includes -Djava.io.tmpdir=$JENKINS_HOME/tmp in its JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS var-declare and ensure that a Jenkins-owned ${JENKINS_HOME}/tmp actually exists.

Ref: 
https://github.com/plus3it/dotc-jenkins/issues/34

Comment: i don't have this file(/etc/sysconfig/jenkins) on my system